# Header format for sending image to nodejs using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, image-uploading

While Sending an image from postman using the setting *image below everything works fine.
[image]

Now implementing same in my Angular 4 app using `angular2-image-upload`

```
<image-upload 
[url]="'xxxxxxxxxxxx'"
[headers]="{header: 'Authorization', value: 'profileImage'}">
```

> Error I get is : Error: Unexpected field

I tried formats to send headers are:

1. `[headers]="{header: 'Authorization', value: 'profileImage'}"`
2. `[headers]="{Authorization: 'profileImage'}"`
3. `[headers]="{fieldname: 'profileImage'}"`
4. `[headers]="{header: 'Authorization', fieldname: 'profileImage'}"`

any help will be great thanks!